# Including rows from base table with left joins when these joins are 'empty'

Tags: mysql

I've got a query which counts the number of reservations in a table over several 15minutes intervals retrieved from an other table:

```
SELECT 
   t.*, count(r.id) as nof_reservations
FROM (
   SELECT time_start, time_end FROM `interval` 
   WHERE time_start < '18:00:00'
   AND time_end > '10:00:00'
) t -- holds a row per 15m interval

-- reservations of the assets
LEFT JOIN reservations r  
ON   start_utc < concat('2017-04-02 ', t.time_end)
AND  end_utc > concat('2017-04-02 ', t.time_start)

-- we need to filter the assets on their type, which is 
-- stored in the assets table
LEFT JOIN assets b 
ON r.asset_id = b.id

WHERE r.deleted_at is null
AND b.asset_type_id = 6 -- asset type we need
GROUP BY t.time_start, t.time_end;
```

This produces the desired table. But when there are no reservations (`nof_reservations=0`) the whole row disappears:

```
| time_start | time_end | nof_reservations |
+------------+----------+------------------+
| 11:00:00   | 11:15:00 | 2                |
| 11:15:00   | 11:30:00 | 2                |
| 11:30:00   | 11:45:00 | 2                |
...
+------------+----------+------------------+
```

As I'm retrieving every interval <1800 >1000 I would have thought to get lines like

```
| time_start | time_end | nof_reservations |
+------------+----------+------------------+
| 10:00:00   | 10:15:00 | 0                |
| 10:15:00   | 10:30:00 | 0                |
| 10:30:00   | 10:45:00 | 0                |
| 10:45:00   | 11:00:00 | 0                |
| 11:00:00   | 11:15:00 | 2                |
| 11:15:00   | 11:30:00 | 2                |
| 11:30:00   | 11:45:00 | 2                |
...
+------------+----------+------------------+
```

What am I missing in the before mentioned query?

Schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE `reservations` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `asset_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_utc` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_utc` datetime NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_van_utc` (`start_utc`),
  KEY `id_tot_utc` (`end_utc`),
  KEY `idx_boot_id` (`asset_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=55 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `assets` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `asset_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `interval` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `time_start` time NOT NULL,
 `time_end` time NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=97 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule of thumb -
when having `... LEFT JOIN t ON ...`, conditions on `t` should be in the `ON` clause and not in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT 
   t.*, count(b.id) as nof_reservations
FROM (
   SELECT time_start, time_end FROM `interval` 
   WHERE time_start < '18:00:00'
   AND time_end > '10:00:00'
) t -- holds a row per 15m interval

-- reservations of the assets
LEFT JOIN reservations r  
ON   start_utc < concat('2017-04-02 ', t.time_end)
AND  end_utc > concat('2017-04-02 ', t.time_start)
AND  r.deleted_at is null

-- we need to filter the assets on their type, which is 
-- stored in the assets table
LEFT JOIN assets b 
ON r.asset_id = b.id
AND b.asset_type_id = 6 -- asset type we need

GROUP BY t.time_start, t.time_end;
```

---

It's possible you want a slightly different join instead (the rest of the query, `SELECT ... FROM ... t` and `GROUP BY` stays the same as above):

```
-- reservations of the assets
-- and filter the assets on their type
LEFT JOIN reservations r  
    JOIN assets b 
    ON r.asset_id = b.id
    AND b.asset_type_id = 6 -- asset type we need
ON   start_utc < concat('2017-04-02 ', t.time_end)
AND  end_utc > concat('2017-04-02 ', t.time_start)
AND  r.deleted_at is null
```

Comment: That's also what I tried to do. But it looks like the `AND b.asset_type_id = 6` does nothing. The nof_reservations column counts every reservation on in the interval; totally discarding the `=6` part....

Comment: Even when commenting the condition out, nothing changes....

Comment: I think what you want to do is to count `b.id` instead of `r.id`. See updated answer

Comment: Since you had not supply a full data sample it is kind of shoot in the dark.

Comment: I added another alternative. Seems they want this ("nested" join).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, I've added it as an alternative answer a moment before :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are dropping the rows because you have a `where` condition on the `assets` table:

`AND b.asset_type_id = 6`

Since you left join through `reservations` to get to `assets` when there are no rows all values in `assets` are null and this condition is removing all of the rows.

I'm not 100% on your schema as it has not been provided but the following should have the result you are after:

```
SELECT 
   t.*, count(r.id) as nof_reservations
FROM (
   SELECT time_start, time_end FROM `interval` 
   WHERE time_start < '18:00:00'
   AND time_end > '10:00:00'
) t -- holds a row per 15m interval

-- reservations of the assets
LEFT JOIN reservations r  
ON   start_utc < concat('2017-04-02 ', t.time_end)
AND  end_utc > concat('2017-04-02 ', t.time_start)

-- we need to filter the assets on their type, which is 
-- stored in the assets table
LEFT JOIN assets b 
ON r.asset_id = b.id
AND b.asset_type_id = 6 -- asset type we need

WHERE r.deleted_at is null
GROUP BY t.time_start, t.time_end;
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added the schema's. Now testing the query. @Mayberg

Comment: This query works, for almost every case. But not if there are only reservations of a type != 6 during an interval. Then the rows are still dropped; as the asset_type_id  != 6 NOR null.

Comment: You are correct, I have updated the above to correct this issue as I was excluding rows that existed in `assets` with a different `asset_type_id`. I have moved the filter to the join condition to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

This is another option:

```
SELECT t.*, count(r.id) as nof_reservations
FROM (
   SELECT time_start, time_end FROM `interval` 
   WHERE time_start < '18:00:00'
   AND time_end > '10:00:00'
) t -- holds a row per 15m interval

-- reservations of the assets
LEFT JOIN reservations r  
JOIN assets b 
ON      r.asset_id = b.id
    AND b.asset_type_id = 6 
    AND r.deleted_at is null
ON      start_utc < concat('2017-04-02 ', t.time_end)
    AND end_utc   > concat('2017-04-02 ', t.time_start)

GROUP BY t.time_start, t.time_end;
```